# Fastest way to compare current time with a given list of times?

Tags: python, datetime

I just want to compare current time (in only hours and minutes) with a given list of times and get the closest time (or just previously available time in the list) value from the list.

```
list_of_times = ['5:00:00 AM',  '5:10:00 AM',   '5:20:00 AM',   '5:30:00 AM',   '5:40:00 AM',   '5:50:00 AM',   '6:00:00 AM',   '6:05:00 AM',   '6:10:00 AM',   '6:15:00 AM',   '6:25:00 AM']
current_time = '6:02:00 AM'
```

What I want:

```
def get_closes_time(current_time , list_of_times ):
    # some logic here
    return closest_time # In this case I want 6:00:00 AM
```

Assuming that my list is in sorted with time, what could be the fastest way of doing this?

Comment: The fastest way will be in O(log n) time and O(1) space.  You will need to use bisection / linear search, and take special care at the endpoints (since times "wrap around" at 12).

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the list of times is sorted?

Comment: Have a look at ["8.6.1. Searching Sorted Lists"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists) in the `bisect` module's documentation for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Binary search for `current_time` in your array. That's the simple part. 
The more complicated part is to define some *comparing* logic between your hours, to decide if your binary search algorithm should continue searching in the left part or the right part of the remaining array.

```
from datetime import datetime

list_of_times = ['5:00:00 AM', '5:10:00 AM', '5:20:00 AM', '5:30:00 AM', '5:40:00 AM', '5:50:00 AM', '6:00:00 AM', '6:05:00 AM', '6:10:00 AM', '6:15:00 AM', '6:25:00 AM']

current_time = '6:02:00 AM'
current = datetime.strptime(current_time, '%I:%M:%S %p')

def getClosestTime(current, list_of_times, left, right):
  if right < 0:
    return "Empty array"
  if right == 0:
    return list_of_times[right]
  if right - 1 == left:
    leftTime = datetime.strptime(list_of_times[left], '%I:%M:%S %p')
    rightTime = datetime.strptime(list_of_times[right], '%I:%M:%S %p')
    if  leftTime < rightTime:
      return leftTime
    else:
      return rightTime

  mid = int((left + right) / 2)
  midTime = datetime.strptime(list_of_times[mid], '%I:%M:%S %p')

  if current < midTime:
    return getClosestTime(current, list_of_times, left, mid - 1)
  if current > midTime:
    return getClosestTime(current, list_of_times, mid + 1, right)
```

This will guarantee a O(log(n)) complexity time, and a O(n) space complexity.

```
getClosestTime(currentTime, listOfTimes, 0, len(listOfTimes) - 1) //that's how you call it
```

Comment: You should use built-in `bisect` module.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this will be the fastest

```
import datetime
list_of_times = ['5:00:00 AM',  '5:10:00 AM',   '5:20:00 AM',   '5:30:00 AM',   '5:40:00 AM',   '5:50:00 AM',   '6:00:00 AM',   '6:05:00 AM',   '6:10:00 AM',   '6:15:00 AM',   '6:25:00 AM']
current_time = '6:02:00 AM'
format = '%I:%M:%S %p'
current_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(current_time, format)
print(sorted([[i,abs(current_time - datetime.datetime.strptime(i, format))] for i in list_of_times], key=lambda x: x[1])[0][0])
```

Above will result to 6:00:00 AM.

Comment: seems good, but with the list comprehension we're already at O(n), muazfaiz asked for the fastest way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_closes_time(current_time , list_of_times ):

    closest_time=list_of_times[0]
    FMT = '%I:%M:%S %p'

    for each in list_of_times:


        dif_1= abs(datetime.strptime(each, FMT) - datetime.strptime(current_time, FMT))
        dif_2= abs(datetime.strptime(closest_time, FMT) - datetime.strptime(current_time, FMT))
        if dif_1<dif_2:
            closest_time=each

    return closest_time
```